# Why Node.js Some Internal Module Register External Reference And Other Module not?

Tags: javascript, c++, node.js

I'm not good at c/c++; I have some problem when I read the node.js source code.

I found some node internal module register external reference, eg:

```
NODE_MODULE_CONTEXT_AWARE_INTERNAL(buffer, node::Buffer::Initialize)
NODE_MODULE_EXTERNAL_REFERENCE(buffer, node::Buffer::RegisterExternalReferences)
```

but other internal module no need register external reference, eg:

```
NODE_MODULE_CONTEXT_AWARE_INTERNAL(fs, node::fs::Initialize)
```

I know node.js snapshot will use external reference; it should all c++ function collect in external reference array, why exist other module no register external reference?

Answer (score 0):

I found the following [here](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/0991dfceceede0b0ad47abf866e571dd5164d231/src/README.md): (there's something about loading during bootstrap)

If the C++ binding is loaded during bootstrap, it needs to be registered with the utilities in node_external_reference.h, like this:

```
namespace node {
namespace utils {
void RegisterExternalReferences(ExternalReferenceRegistry* registry) {
  registry->Register(GetHiddenValue);
  registry->Register(SetHiddenValue);
  // ... register all C++ functions used to create FunctionTemplates.
}
}  // namespace util
}  // namespace node

// The first argument passed to `NODE_MODULE_EXTERNAL_REFERENCE`,
// which is `util` here, needs to be added to the
// `EXTERNAL_REFERENCE_BINDING_LIST_BASE` list in node_external_reference.h
NODE_MODULE_EXTERNAL_REFERENCE(util, node::util::RegisterExternalReferences)
```